# No me loguea al iniciar sesón

Tags: laravel-5

He estado trabajando en como enviar emails por mi aplicación y en esto que he perdido la capacidad de loguearme en ella, lo único que he cambiado del núcleo de laravel ha sido que he añadido las líneas

```
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
        $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

en el archivo StreamBuffer en la linea 263.
He puesto un breakpoint en el archivo web.php para ver si entraba en la ruta, y en vez de eso se pasa tres veces por la misma ruta pero no me entra en la aplicación, ¿alguna idea?

También he editado por supuesto el archivo .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=libreir.mr@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

y el config:

```
return [



'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),



'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),


'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),


'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'libreir.mr@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Maria Rosa Cambero'),
],



'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),


'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),


'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',



'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto después de hacer un config:clear? Porque es muy molesto el tener que recurrir todo el rato a versiones anteriores...

Comment: ¿estás modificando archivos de la carpeta vendor?

Comment: He modificado un archivo y al volver atrás resulta que es eso el problema, ¿no es así? Es que me daba un problema muy molesto cuando mandaba emails: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0] ¿Alguna manera de solventar ese problema de otro modo?

Comment: ¿qué versión de php usas?

Comment: La versión 7.1.11

Comment: y como configuraste el .env para usar a gmail como servidor smtp?

Comment: Pues puse la siguiente configuración y desde entonces no me entra en la aplicación                                                     
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=libreir.mr@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Comment: Probá con la respuesta que dí en este otro [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144412/error-mandar-email-al-subir-al-hosting-con-laravel/144826?noredirect=1#comment271976_144826) a ver si te sirve.

Comment: El problema es que no puedo probarlo porque no me deja iniciar sesión al haber cambiado el .env